# Error setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence "seq" (1..9223372036854775807)

Tags: postgresql

In the project I am working, we use PostgreSQL and when the c# code which runs the following statement:

```
INSERT INTO directory (id, reference, created) 
VALUES (DEFAULT, DEFAULT, default) 
RETURNING id, reference;
```

we got the following error:
    setval: value 0 is out of bounds for sequence "directory_seq" (1..9223372036854775807)

What could be the reason? or what is a possible solution? thanks in advance

Comment: Any trigger on that table?

Comment: no, nothing, just a primary key

Comment: please include the database schema, this looks weird...

Comment: sorry, i had to wait for the green light from my client.. this file is a bit long.. in your opinion, is there another way than to paste it here?

Comment: @BjörnNilsson hi, we still can't solve it. Do you mean the query itself or the postgreSQL response looks weird?

Answer (score 2):

looks like the minimum value is 1 probably from the sequence that the id column is pulling from and you are trying to set it to 0 in your insert?  Maybe in the insert you could leave off the setting of the id value and it will get set itself.